# OnItemClickListener not called with custom layout row in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have such a problem. I'm trying to get id of row in `ListView`. To do so I'm using `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
wyswietlenieZadan = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.zadania, R.id.opisZadania, listaZadan);
wyswietlenieZadan.setAdapter(mAdapter);
wyswietlenieZadan.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Twoje id: " +id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Here is my `zadania.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opisZadania"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:id="@+id/task"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="usunZadanie"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/opisZadania"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/task"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/task"
        android:onClick="edytujZadanie"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesnt work but when I use `simple_list_item_1.xml` as layout instead of `zadania.xml`, I can get id of each record. Anybody knows why it doesn't work with my custom layout?

Comment: why should you use `simple_list_item_1.xml`?

Comment: I dont want to use simple_list_item_1. But with this the SetOnItemClicklistener works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Twoje id: " +id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Twoje id: " +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

as the position variable gives you the position of the item you just clicked. If you clicked the first item it will show Twoje id:0 and if you clicked the second item it would show Twoje id:1 and so on...